# One or more parameter values were invalid dynamoDB + Java

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to create a table in DynamoDB. I could use DynamoDB console but I prefer doing it via Java. But the following code is giving exception and I can't find why..

Please check the following code..

```
String serviceRef = "ServiceRef";
ArrayList<KeySchemaElement> keySchema = new ArrayList<KeySchemaElement>();
keySchema.add(new KeySchemaElement()
        .withAttributeName("ServiceID")
        .withKeyType(KeyType.HASH));

ArrayList<AttributeDefinition> attributeDefinitions = new ArrayList<AttributeDefinition>();
attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition()
        .withAttributeName("ServiceID")
        .withAttributeType(ScalarAttributeType.N)
        .withAttributeName("ServiceName")
        .withAttributeType(ScalarAttributeType.S)
        .withAttributeName("CreatedDateUTC")
        .withAttributeType(ScalarAttributeType.N)
        .withAttributeName("UpdatedDateUTC")
        .withAttributeType(ScalarAttributeType.N)
        .withAttributeName("IsDeleted")
        .withAttributeType(ScalarAttributeType.B));

CreateTableRequest request = new CreateTableRequest()
        .withTableName(serviceRef)
        .withKeySchema(keySchema)
        .withAttributeDefinitions(attributeDefinitions)
        .withProvisionedThroughput(
                new ProvisionedThroughput().withReadCapacityUnits(5L).withWriteCapacityUnits(1L));

System.out.println("Issuing create table request for: " + serviceRef);
dynamoDBClient.createTable(request);
System.out.println("Waiting for table Name: " + serviceRef + " to be created...");
try {
    Tables.awaitTableToBecomeActive(dynamoDBClient, serviceRef);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What is wrong with this code? 
The error it is giving is -

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Some index key attributes are not defined in AttributeDefinitions. Keys: [ServiceID], AttributeDefinitions: [IsDeleted] (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: SA8P5UUVH37T8P1R7F6VVPP357VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1219)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:803)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:505)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:317)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1803)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.createTable(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:832)
    at com.rit.randemmiddleware.controller.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:38)
```

Also what to use in space of

```
Tables.awaitTableToBecomeActive(dynamoDBClient, serviceRef);
```

As it is showing deprecated.

Comment: To test for table active, the javadoc suggests you use TableUtils.waitUntilActive(AmazonDynamoDB, String).

Answer (score 4):

You're misusing AttributeDefinition method chaining. You've mistakenly created **one** attribute definition whose name you keep changing (from "ServiceID" to "ServiceName" to "CreatedDateUTC" etc., and finally to "IsDeleted").

You need to provide an array or collection of attribute definitions. For example:

```
attributeDefinitions.add(
    new AttributeDefinition()
        .withAttributeName("ServiceID")
        .withAttributeType(ScalarAttributeType.N),
    new AttributeDefinition()
        .withAttributeName("ServiceName")
        .withAttributeType(ScalarAttributeType.S),
    ...
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I made a very basic mistake. After changing my code accordingly now I can create my table.

Answer (score 4):

It is also necessary to mention that AttributeDefinitions should contain only columns that are necessary for table decalration/description (KeySchema and GlobalSecondaryIndexes). Because DynamoDB is schemaless.

If you will try to create a table with more attributes than is necessary for indexes, you will get an error like:`Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Some AttributeDefinitions are not used. AttributeDefinitions: [Precipitation, Temperature, Rank, ID, Date, Location], keys used: [ID, Date, Location]`

I came here with the following case:

Attribute Definitions:

```
attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition("ID", "S"));
attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition("Location", "S"));
attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition("Date", "S"));
attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition("Precipitation", "N"));
attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition("Temperature", "N"));
attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition("Rank", "N"));
```

Key Schema:

```
tableKeySchema.add(new KeySchemaElement("ID", KeyType.HASH))
```

Global Secondary Index:

```
GlobalSecondaryIndex locationDateIndex = new GlobalSecondaryIndex()
            .withIndexName("Location_Date-Index")
            .withProjection(new 
Projection().withProjectionType(ProjectionType.ALL))
            .withProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput(10l, 1l))
            .withKeySchema(new KeySchemaElement("Location", KeyType.HASH))
            .withKeySchema(new KeySchemaElement("Date", KeyType.RANGE));
```

Create Table Request:

```
CreateTableRequest createTableRequest = new CreateTableRequest()
    .withTableName(tableName)
    .withProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput(5L, 1L))
    .withAttributeDefinitions(attributeDefinitions)
    .withKeySchema(tableKeySchema)
    .withGlobalSecondaryIndexes(locationDateIndex);
```

And the error from above:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: 
One or more parameter values were invalid: Some AttributeDefinitions are not used. 
AttributeDefinitions: [Precipitation, Temperature, Rank, ID, Date, Location], 
keys used: [ID, Date, Location] (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; 
Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: ...)
```

Reducing Attribute Definition List solved my problem:

```
attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition("ID", "S"));
attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition("Location", "S"));
attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition("Date", "S"));
```

PS: I answer here because this page is relevant for my request in Google.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer this question, this helped me resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have only created a single `AttributeDefinition`. Your method chaining only produces a single `AttributeDefinition`, rather than a list of them. You also only need to create an `AttributeDefinition` for attributes that are for your `KeySchema` of your table or your GSIs.

```
attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition()
        .withAttributeName("ServiceID")
        .withAttributeType(ScalarAttributeType.N));
```

For your deprecation question, look at the [Javadoc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/util/Tables.html) of `Tables`:

> **Deprecated.**
>
> Use [`TableUtils`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/util/TableUtils.html).

```
TablesUtils.waitUntilActive(dynamoDBClient, serviceRef);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can create my code now. But from that I got another question. What happens if I create an empty table? Will it become active? Current Exception I am getting is....                  Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Table ServiceRef never became active
 at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.util.TableUtils.waitUntilActive(TableUtils.java:150)
 at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.util.TableUtils.waitUntilActive(TableUtils.java:117)
 at com.rit.randemmiddleware.controller.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:47)

Comment: @GourabBanerjee Are you using DynamoDB Local, or are you running against an endpoint?

Comment: No. I used credentials to directly connect to the Amazon SQS. And yes I am using US_WEST_2 as an regional end point.